# How to make a select of 2 rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, not-exists

I have two tables `users` and `blocked` the function that i want to make is a funcion like `Facebook`, `Instagram`, etc., when a user block another, I mean if I user 8 block the user 9 the user 9 can't see me but he can see all the other users

the way that I'm trying to make the query is the next

```
 Select * from users WHERE id NOT IN 
(Select idblock from blocked where blocked.idBlock = users.id);
```

this is the table of blocked

[image]

and this is the table of users

[image]

the issue that i have is that when i login with the user with id 3 is ok, but when i login whit the user with another id doesn't show the others users

what i expect of the query is this (what is right)

[image]

as you can see in the table of blocked, the ohters id's (users) block me except the id 11, but if i get logged like the id user 10 show me this

[image]

so i don't whant this because the id 10 isn't blocked

i hope someone understand me

Comment: Could you provide your expect result when you id = 3?

Comment: @D-Shih i update the question

Comment: I have answered you can try it  @cesg.dav

Comment: @D-Shih thanks it works like i whant!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write `NOT exists` on subquery and check `b.IdBlocked` in subquery.

```
SELECT *
FROM users u 
WHERE NOT exists 
(
  Select idblock 
  from blocked b 
  where b.idBlock = u.id AND b.IdBlocked = 3
) AND u.id <> 3
```

sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c14ee/13

If `User ID = 3` then

**Results**:

```
| ID |
|----|
| 11 |
```

If `User ID = 10` then

```
SELECT *
FROM users u 
WHERE NOT exists 
(
  Select idblock 
  from blocked b 
  where b.idBlock = u.id AND b.IdBlocked = 10
) AND u.id <> 10
```

**Results**:

```
| ID |
|----|
|  3 |
|  8 |
|  9 |
| 11 |
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `LEFT JOIN` to accomplish the required output.

What the following query does is attempt to match block requests for the specified user (#3) against all other users in the database (`LEFT JOIN`), and only return those users who haven't been blocked (`WHERE b.id IS NULL`).

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN blocked b ON (u.id = b.idBlock AND b.idBlocked = 3)
WHERE u.id <> 3
AND b.id IS NULL;
```